# How to use brew install jenkins-lts@version?

Tags: macos, jenkins

[Installer Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQ53I.png)

the output is :
Downloading https:formulae.brew.sh/api/formula.jws.json
Warning :No available formula with the name "jenkins-lts@2.249.3". Did you mean jenkins-lts?
Searching for similarly named formulae and casks...
Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/cask.jws.json

Formulae
jenkins-lts

I can install jenkins-lts with brew `install jenkins-lts`, but I want to use the version 2.xxx.xx, which already works on my old online game pipeline, with lots of script functions.

When I try to install jenkins-lts with brew: success.
When I try to install jenkins-lts@2.249.3 with brew: fail

I do not want to use the latest lts version. Please help me.

Comment: Please do not provide your output as screenshots. Copy and  paste them here, so one can clearly see.